# Variables inside of `ssh` execution and formatting

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

I am writing a shell script and I need to SSH into a server, perform some actions, and then exit.

To do this, I am using code such as below:

```
ssh -t username@server '
cd uploads/; \
tar -xvzf torrent.tar.gz; \
'
```

However, I need to use a variable like so:

```
DIR="uploads/";

ssh -t username@server '
cd $DIR; \
tar -xvzf torrent.tar.gz; \
'
```

This doesn't seem to work because obviously the `cd` isn't being executed until the SSH connection is made, and by then there is no `$DIR` variable (my guess). However, is there any way I could use a variable?

Perhaps a better question is, is there a better way I could lay out my script to perform actions once the SSH connection is made? I am having to be careful, escaping apostrophes, and at one point I am actually SSHing to another server from inside an SSH connection. This is ugly code!

**Edit:** Just read that if I use " instead of ', the variable will work. However my question still stands about formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use double quotes to allow expansion. e.g. try this:

```
echo "$DIR"
```

vs

```
echo '$DIR'
```

and note the result.

It's worth wrapping this in a shell script thus:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
# ...
```

and the -x will output shell expansions etc. It makes life very easy for debugging.

Rather than using the above means to feed in commands, you can use a [heredoc](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html). e.g.

```
ssh username@host <<EOF
ls
EOF
```

will execute 'ls' on the remote host.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo! :(

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if the only way to execute commands on the server once is the connection is made is by using double quotes after the SSH command, or is there another way that is perhaps neater for shell scripting?

Comment: See above for the heredoc info

Comment: The herodc looks like the solution I need. However, I have a prompt in my program, and heredoc doesn’t seem to prompt the user anymore: `ssh $SERVER <<EOF                                                                   
  cd downloads/;                                                                     
  read -e -p "Enter the path to the file: " FILEPATH`

Answer (score 0):

instead of single quotes (') why don't you use double quotes (") then the $DIR should be expanded

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to write :

```
   ssh username@server "( cd $DIR; tar -xvzf torrent.tar.gz; )"
```

this should execute  after connection.. 
if not try with *("* instead of *"(* and obviusly then close